# Browser issue search code is working in Firefox not in Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I have issue with browser, I have code in jsfiddle which shows me match result by providing input.
but it working fine in FF not in IE

jquery version in jsfiddle is jquery 1.9.1
IE ver. 9 , FF version 24.0

```
$("#searchInput").keyup(function () {
    //split the current value of searchInput
    var data = this.value.toLowerCase().split(" ");

    //create a jquery object of the rows
    var jo = $("#selectbox").find("option");
    if (this.value == "") {
        jo.show();
        return;
    }
    //hide all the rows
    jo.hide();

    //Recusively filter the jquery object to get results.
    jo.filter(function (i, v) {
        var $t = $(this);
        for (var d = 0; d < data.length; ++d) {
            if ($t.is(":contains('" + data[d] + "')")) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    })
    //show the rows that match.
    .show();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SBjDb/

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors? Also, please describe the problem better than 'it doesn't work'. What are you expecting to happen? What does happen? etc.

Comment: I have data in select box, when I input data, it match with available data in select box and gives result. You can see result in FF. I am not getting any error in console when I debug in IE

Comment: I don't think IE lets you hide option elements. If you try `$("option").hide();` or directly set it in CSS with `option { display : none; }` nothing happens... I vaguely recall looking into this months ago, and I think the solution was basically to `.detach()` the options rather than hiding them, and then re-insert them as required.

Comment: @nnnnnn so can i use .detach()

Comment: hi @nnnnnn but detach() removes all items from select box

Comment: hi @user2826111::: i prefer this way for searching http://jsfiddle.net/m25UW/

Comment: @maverickosama92 you are correct but your jsfiddle not working in IE9

Comment: No, `.detach()` doesn't remove all items, it removes whichever items you tell it to remove.

Comment: @nnnnnn you can try by replacing .hide to .detach

Comment: If you make no changes to your existing code other than replacing _.hide()_ with _.detach()_ it obviously won't work. That's not what I suggested. You have to keep a reference to detached items so that you can re-insert them later. You'd have to change the _.show()_ code too. In other words you'd have to actually stop and think about how detaching and re-inserting options might help produce the effect you're looking for, and restructure your code appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
// on keydown on text box
$("#txtInput").on("keyup", function (e) {                   
    var txt = $(this).val().toLowerCase();  

    //if backspace pressed refresh list
    if (e.which == 8) {
        if (txt.length == 0) {
            renderList(arrText);
        }
    }

    if (txt.length >= 1) {
        var filterList = searchInList(arrText, txt);
        if (filterList.length > 0) {
            renderList(filterList);
        } else {            
            renderList(arrText);
        }
    }                     
});
```

will also work in IE9 as well, fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/m25UW/1/

Comment: hide/show options i think only works in firefox, in my browsers, chrome and ie9 your fiddle is not working either.